# Combining different power sources for hybrid power plants

Tags: power-supply

How can we combine two different power sources? For eg:AC output from a windmill and DC from a panel situated near? Will the combined output be greater?

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean by "combine" them? Put them in series? In parallel? Why are you doing this? If you put them in series the AC output will be riding on top of the DC voltage. The output will be greater than the DC alone when the AC voltage is positive, but lower when the AC voltage is negative.

Comment: Null its actually for a college project.Project is actually on witricity for hybrid power plants.Our model has a magnetron which is to be powered with two different power sources as per the topic.We have  dc suppply from a solar pqnel and an ac source.We have to combine these two sources somehow and the out put of the combined circuit should be ac which is the magnetron input.Could you help us with any working idea or circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Im not entirely sure but there are two ways in my opinion.

One has already been mentioned by Grant, which is to rectify the AC output from the windmill to DC and then use it to charge the battery. Similarily, DC output from the solar panels can also be used to charge a battery using appropriate charge controllers. The combined storage can be utilised as DC or as AC (using inverters) as required. This is generally used in the standalone systems.

Another might be to use a bus, to which you can add the power plants with using various controllers and interface devices. This topology is used in the microgrids and grid connected systems.

The combined output in terms of power will obviously be greater as you are producing power in both cases and adding them. The voltages and currents from the output can be obtained as required by various control techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the AC output of the windmill gets rectified to DC and the two power sources used to charge a battery.

There are already devices out there specifically for this task - called "hybrid charge controllers".

The total power output will be that of both the wind and solar sources (minus any conversion and efficiency losses).  So it will be greater than one source alone, if that is what you mean.